# Alphabetical order with my locale

Tags: c, string

I'm wondering if there's a function that compares two variables of type `wchar_t` in alphabetical order (after setting my locale - in my case the code is

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "pl_PL.UTF-8");
```

Someone suggested `wcscoll` which doesn't give me much, because it compares strings (i.e. `wchar_t *`). If I have two variables, `a,b` of type `wchar_t`, then calling `wcscoll(&a, &b)` doesn't work properly

I'd appreciate some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "No". Locale-dependent collation is a function on two strings, not on two characters. You can collate two one-character-long strings, but that's not quite the same as two individual characters.

As was suggested, you use `wcscoll` to compare two wstrings. In order to convert the wchars into wstrings, you need to create null-terminated wchar_t arrays. So you could use a function like this:

```
int wc_collate(wchar_t a, wchar_t b) {
  return wcscoll((wchar_t[2]){a, 0}, (wchar_t[2]){b, 0});
}
```

I couldn't find anything in the C standard to justify my claim in the first paragraph, but the [Posix rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap07.html#tag_21_07_03_02) is more forthcoming:

> The rules governing collation depend to some extent on the use. At least five different levels of increasingly complex collation rules can be distinguished:
>
> 1. Byte/machine code order: This is the historical collation order in the UNIX system and many proprietary operating systems. Collation is here performed character by character, without any regard to context. The primary virtue is that it usually is quite fast and also completely deterministic; it works well when the native machine collation sequence matches the user expectations.
> 2. Character order: On this level, collation is also performed character by character, without regard to context. The order between characters is, however, not determined by the code values, but on the expectations by the user of the "correct" order between characters. In addition, such a (simple) collation order can specify that certain characters collate equally (for example, uppercase and lowercase letters).
> 3. String ordering: On this level, entire strings are compared based on relatively straightforward rules. Several "passes'' may be required to determine the order between two strings. Characters may be ignored in some passes, but not in others; the strings may be compared in different directions; and simple string substitutions may be performed before strings are compared. This level is best described as "dictionary" ordering; it is based on the spelling, not the pronunciation, or meaning, of the words.
> 4. Text search ordering: This is a further refinement of the previous level, best described as "telephone book ordering''; some common homonyms (words spelled differently but with the same pronunciation) are collated together; numbers are collated as if they were spelled out, and so on.
> 5. Semantic-level ordering: Words and strings are collated based on their meaning; entire words (such as "the") are eliminated; the ordering is not deterministic. This usually requires special software and is highly dependent on the intended use.
>
> While the historical collation order formally is at level 1, for the English language it corresponds roughly to elements at level 2. The user expects to see the output from the ls utility sorted very much as it would be in a dictionary. While telephone book ordering would be an optimal goal for standard collation, this was ruled out as the order would be language-dependent. Furthermore, a requirement was that the order must be determined solely from the text string and the collation rules; no external information (for example, "pronunciation dictionaries") could be required.
>
> As a result, the goal for the collation support is at level 3.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing pointers to a single wide character. wcscoll expects strings terminated by a null wide character.

Answer (score 0):

`wcscoll()` expects null terminated strings as parameters, which is mhy `wcscoll(&a, &b)` with variables `a`, `b` of type `wchar_t` is not working as expected.

As quick and dirty workaround you might want to try something like:

```
wchar_t A[2];
wchar_t B[2];

A[1]='\0';
B[1]='\0';

A[0] = a;
B[0] = b;
```

and call `wcscoll(A, B)`instead.

Not 100% sure about it, I strongly doubt, what you are looking for exists and is possible, as there seem to be writing systems requiring more than one character to determine collation order.

The Unicode Technical Standard #10
Unicode Collation Algorithm (see: http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/) mentions the following example

> In Slovak, the digraph ch sorts as if it were a separate letter after h.